# wpf datagrid rowheader expander togglebuttton style from resource dictionary

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a WPF DataGrid with RowDetails which uses the RowHeader Expander to expand/collapse the RowDetails.
I am trying to set the style of the RowHeader Expander ToggleButton to a ToggleButton style defined in a resource dictionary. I tried this:

```
<DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>
<DataTemplate>
    <Expander Expanded="Expander_Expanded" Collapsed="Expander_Collapsed" >
        <Style TargetType="ToggleButton" BasedOn="{StaticResource ExpandCollapseToggleStyle}" />
    </Expander>
</DataTemplate>
```

This compiles but does not change the style of the ToggleButton.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not quite that easy.  If you are forcing an `Expander` into your `RowHeaderTemplate`, you need to style the actual `Expander` object in order to have an impact on the `ToggleButton` buried within it.

Given below is the default styling for the `Expander` object in the Aero.Normal WPF theme.  Using that as a base, you can then modify the `ToggleButton` contained within.

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Type Expander}"
       TargetType="{x:Type Expander}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground"
            Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
    <Setter Property="Background"
            Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment"
            Value="Stretch"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment"
            Value="Stretch"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
            Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness"
            Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Expander}">
                <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        CornerRadius="3"
                        SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                    <DockPanel>
                        <ToggleButton x:Name="HeaderSite"
                                      DockPanel.Dock="Top"
                                      Margin="1"
                                      MinWidth="0"
                                      MinHeight="0"
                                      Style="{StaticResource ExpanderDownHeaderStyle}"
                                      FocusVisualStyle="{StaticResource ExpanderHeaderFocusVisual}"
                                      IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsExpanded,Mode=TwoWay,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                      Content="{TemplateBinding Header}"
                                      ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}"
                                      ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplateSelector}"
                                      Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                                      Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                      FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}"
                                      FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}"
                                      FontStyle="{TemplateBinding FontStyle}"
                                      FontStretch="{TemplateBinding FontStretch}"
                                      FontWeight="{TemplateBinding FontWeight}"
                                      HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                      VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="ExpandSite"
                                          DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"
                                          Visibility="Collapsed"
                                          Focusable="false"
                                          HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                          VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                          Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"/>
                    </DockPanel>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsExpanded"
                             Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility"
                                Value="Visible"
                                TargetName="ExpandSite"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="ExpandDirection"
                             Value="Right">
                        <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock"
                                Value="Right"
                                TargetName="ExpandSite"/>
                        <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock"
                                Value="Left"
                                TargetName="HeaderSite"/>
                        <Setter Property="Style"
                                Value="{StaticResource ExpanderRightHeaderStyle}"
                                TargetName="HeaderSite"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="ExpandDirection"
                             Value="Up">
                        <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock"
                                Value="Top"
                                TargetName="ExpandSite"/>
                        <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock"
                                Value="Bottom"
                                TargetName="HeaderSite"/>
                        <Setter Property="Style"
                                Value="{StaticResource ExpanderUpHeaderStyle}"
                                TargetName="HeaderSite"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="ExpandDirection"
                             Value="Left">
                        <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock"
                                Value="Left"
                                TargetName="ExpandSite"/>
                        <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock"
                                Value="Right"
                                TargetName="HeaderSite"/>
                        <Setter Property="Style"
                                Value="{StaticResource ExpanderLeftHeaderStyle}"
                                TargetName="HeaderSite"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled"
                             Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground"
                                Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Thanks, using this Style as is gives me a runtime error that ExpanderDownHeaderStyle resource cannot be found. Perhaps because I am referencing Aero2? Can you tell me how you generated this xaml? Perhaps I can generate it from a datagrid using Aero2.

Comment: Yes, you will get an error trying to use this as is.  This is just the base Expander style.  You need to create the style you want for the toggle and then modify the expander appropriately.